# How to properly add admin panel in Angular build in project

Tags: angular

I have created a website using angular 6 now i need to create an admin panel that makes my website dynamic. So what is the best approach to doing that Can i create a new angular app for admin panel or within website app.
If i create admin panel in the website app then the problem is default style is conflict with admin style and website header is shown in the admin template. Website app have 9 component and admin panel have 15 component then its difficult to manage. 
So basically i want to know if i have to create a website + admin panel then what is the standard way and folder structure to manage both of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, I would go with this approach of creating a new project for the ADMIN PANEL. It's just another component that you will most likely share the state, services and many sub-components within your application.

Just generate a new component. The folder structure could be organized in so many flavours. One that I currently like is listed below:

-api
-core
-features
-scss
-utils

Your admin panel could be inside features (or even core) depending on how are you planning to do it.